# Is it correct to say second maximum?

Tags: superlative-degree

I've seen, "second largest" being used more often. 
Is there any special reason that, "second maximum", is not a correct thing expression?

For example, if I have an array of numbers: 1,2,3, is it correct to state that 2 is the second maximum number?

Comment: 'Maximum' _tends_ to be used for counts of articles, people etc (and of course measures like heights, weights, temperatures) rather than pure numbers. Also, in pure maths, a maximum is a point on a curve. 'Second maximum' sounds outlandish when used of numbers.  It's more a style thing than a logic thing. We have to live with it.

Comment: @0user would you say "the second unique value" ?

Comment: @0user Second greatest, second largest, second biggest, but not second maximum. See the answer below.

Comment: *Second maximum* would make complete sense in the game of snooker. In that game, a *maximum* is the highest possible score of 147 points. Therefore, a *second maximum* would be the second time a player has achieved that score. The same could be said for math, where something has reached a maximum value for the second time. Of course, that doesn't sound like the exact context of your question. Then again, the word *maximum* itself doesn't make much sense with respect to your question either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience "maximum" refers to a singular value. In calculus you can have "local maximum" of a curve that is not the global maximum of the curve.

In statistics, however, you can rank values. You can have a "highest rank" and "second highest rank". But even there I don't hear "second maximum" as a common phrase.

There is also "sub-maximum" but I hear it in things that aren't easily counted. "He gave a sub-maximal effort".